# Error function of the second moment of the divisor function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, divisors

It is easy to show that the second moment of the divisor function has asymptotics:
$$\sum_{n\leq x} d_0(n)^2 = xP(\log(x))+E_2(x)$$
Where $P$ is some polynomial and that:
$$E_2 = o(x)$$
Previously, some bounds have been shown on the growth of $E_2$. I found this paper which appears to be state of art, though I do not trust myself to do literature reviews sometimes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4041

Does anybody know if this can be improved or if this is the best we know? What about assuming RH?

Comment: Checking on Google Scholar the 13 citations of the paper you linked above, it seems that there is no further improvement. At least as late as 2016 (Shiu, P. The mean-square value of the divisor function) it is claimed to be the current best estimate.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks, that was what I had found also (and was hoping for)